# Javascript or JQuery on Wordpress+Elementor blog for a show/hide button

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, elementor

On my personal blog, I would like to **insert 3 buttons** that have the **function of showing/hiding** **3 different elements** and I would also like to have the possibility to use the **same code for labels/texts**, if possible, to ensure that when clicked, a highlighted text , show or hide content like buttons do.
I tried using some code found on the web and the only one that works is this(read down) one but I'm not sure if it's right. the website started working even without this code until i did a general cache cleanup.
can you help me to write a suitable code that can work with my requirements?
Could you also explain how I can **change the text of the button when it is clicked**?
For example from "Show content" to "Hide content".
I am attaching the **jquery code** that works for me. **javascript didn't work with the site**.

**if you need data:**

**button:       function:**
btn1          show/hide
btn2          show/hide
btn3          show/hide

**label:        function:**
lbl1          show/hide
lbl2          show/hide
lbl3          show/hide

**paragraph:    description:**
p1            paragraph that appears and disappears when you click the text or button
p2            paragraph that appears and disappears when you click the text or button
p3            paragraph that appears and disappears when you click the text or button

**CODE:**

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
   jQuery( "#show_01" ).click(function() {
        jQuery(".changing_image").hide();
            jQuery("#01").fadeToggle();
            jQuery(".our_nav").removeClass("my_active");
            jQuery("#show_01").addClass("my_active");
     });
        
        jQuery( "#show_02" ).click(function() {
        jQuery(".changing_image").hide();
            jQuery("#02").fadeToggle();
            jQuery(".our_nav").removeClass("my_active");
            jQuery("#show_02").addClass("my_active");
     });
        
        jQuery( "#show_03" ).click(function() {
        jQuery(".changing_image").hide();
            jQuery("#03").fadeToggle();
            jQuery(".our_nav").removeClass("my_active");
            jQuery("#show_03").addClass("my_active");
     });
        
        jQuery( "#show_04" ).click(function() {
        jQuery(".changing_image").hide();
            jQuery("#04").fadeToggle();
            jQuery(".our_nav").removeClass("my_active");
            jQuery("#show_04").addClass("my_active");
     });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of getting the element by ID and then immediately calling the on-click function, you should store it in a variable. Then add the on click function. This way you can use the variable to reference the button and change its inner HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be a solution that might work for what you are looking to do...

```
<style>
/* Hide content by default */
.content {
  display: none;
}
</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<!-- some example buttons and content divs... -->
<button class='button' id="1">Show content 1</button>
<button class='button' id="2">Show content 2</button>
<button class='button' id="3">Show content 3</button>

<div class="content 1">Content 1 goes here</div>
<div class="content 2">Content 2 goes here</div>
<div class="content 3">Content 3 goes here</div>



<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Hide content on content click
  $(".content").click(function() {
    id = $(this).attr("id");
    // now change text of button that has id = id
    $(".button#" + id).text("Show content " + id);
    $(this).hide();
    
  });
  
  // Toggle content on button click
  $(".button").click(function() {
    var buttonId = $(this).attr("id");
    var contentClass = ".content." + buttonId.slice(-1);
    
    $(contentClass).toggle();
    $(this).text(function(i, text){
      return text === "Show content " + buttonId.slice(-1) ? "Hide content " + buttonId.slice(-1) : "Show content " + buttonId.slice(-1);
    })
  });
});
</script>
```